# Modify DNS local tables to test user experience

Tags: ubuntu, dns

Im trying to implement some algorithms that I've developed for my thesis research in a real scenario. Basically, I have gathered my DNS traffic from the last month and I'm getting my most 'relevant' domains by TF-IDF metric. Which basically represent the domains I have used the most in several days. More precisely my algorithms relies on blocking/swapping of small % of the domains given by TF-IDF metric, lets say block my top 1% domains by TF-IDF. Thus,to ensure the privacy for some attackers models (ML classifiers) where the DNS resolver is compromised or even the DNS resolver is targeting us based on our queries (ideally this needs to be deployed in a real network).

I want to measure the performance of the network and test the user experience through the day. Im using Ubuntu 18.04.6. How can I manually set some local TTL values in my cache for saying 1 year to my top 1% (i.e 300 domain names)? And verify if the 'block' worked? Basically if I can sniff the DNS packets, the request does not have to appear in the trace, because the query or domain name is returned from my cache. How can I implement something like this? Any idea will be much appreciated TIA.

Comment: You want to override the Name/IP address mapping for selected DNS names?

Comment: @roaima Not override but block specific DNS names. This means a block for the end-user but the DNS resolver is still getting the same ammount of requests in general. Basically I want to check how anoying are my algorithms for the end-user, maybe see some 404, or some elements of a website do not load because the real TTL has changed.

Comment: What should happen (at the DNS level) when a DNS name is "blocked"?

Comment: The resolution should always be done from my local cache due to the 'hardcoded' ttl, instead of sending the query through the entire dns hierarchy to resolve the domain once the actual ttl has expired. Therefore, theoretically a dynamic web site should return more obsolete content as time goes by.

Comment: run a local copy of bind, spoof the domains you want to block and either point them to 0.0.0.0 or send 'em to some local webserver, etc.

Comment: "_Therefore, theoretically a dynamic web site should return more obsolete content as time goes by_" - no, not even slightly. DNS resolves domain names to IP address. If this is the result you're expecting you should be investigating a caching web proxy, not DNS

Comment: My bad, thats a wrong hypothesis, you are correct @roaima, but basically how can I do this to see the behavior in the end-user (me)?

Comment: It's not clear what behaviour you're seeking. Caching DNS is very unlikely to make any visible difference over a short timeframe unless you're in the habit of accessing services hosted in people's homes on DHCP-based addresses

Comment: Exactly, for example "blocking" CNN website  means that I will set a very long ttl, thus the resolution always be done from my cache, and dynamic content provided by the delivered networks will change over the time. I want to see if the content is oudtated, or something in the next day or next two days. I actually dont know the expected behavior that the reason why Im trying to implement this.

Comment: Your premise is false and therefore the question as asked has little meaning. I have already explained that content will not change just because you have long TTLs on DNS lookups, and that you seem to be confusing a DNS proxy with a Web proxy. You could have a five year TTL against DNS records for the servers I run at work and you'd have no change - because we don't change DNS hosting records very often. Web content, however, is updated daily